# Nested If Statement not Evaluating as expected

Tags: python

I have two lists that I am trying to compare :

```
a = [{'name': 'ORANGES_060222', 'bushels': 5}, {'name': 'BANANAS_062620', 'bushels': 3}]

b = ['oranges', 'bananas', 'apples']
```

I just want to see if any element of a's name value can be matched to b and if so append the bushel value to an empty list. Like so:

```
f = []
a = [{'name': 'ORANGES_060222', 'bushels': 5}, {'name': 'BANANAS_062620', 'bushels': 3}]
b = ['oranges', 'bananas', 'apples']
for item in a:
    if item['name'].lower() in b:
        f.append(item['bushels'])
    print(f)
```

`f` is returning [], the problem seems to be in the if statement. Not sure but seems like I might be attempting the wrong operation there?

Comment: Your `item['name'].lower()` is e.g. `oranges_060222`, which doesn't lie in `b`. If the pattern is always `<fruit>_<number>`, you can do `if item['name'].lower().split("_")[0] in b:` instead.

Comment: Have you tried walking through the code on paper?

Comment: Sorry, I suffer from dyslexia, coding is very challenging for me but it keeps me busy...I understand what you are saying. I think I understood the logic could go the other way right? if orange in item['name'].lower()?

Answer (score 1):

`item['name'].lower() in b` won't work as you intend because the strings don't match exactly. For instance `'ORANGES_060222'` isn't the same as `'orange'` (even with `lower`).

Instead you can remove all non alphabet characters using `isalpha`

```
item_name = ''.join([c for c in item['name'].lower() if c.isalpha()])
if item_name in b:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something like this -

```
f = []
a = [{'name': 'ORANGES_060222', 'bushels': 5}, {'name': 'BANANAS_062620', 'bushels': 3}]
b = ['oranges', 'bananas', 'apples']
for item in a:
    for b_items in b:
        if b_items in item['name'].lower():
            f.append(item['bushels'])
            
print(f)
```

**Output :**

```
[5, 3]
```

What this does is checks if any of b exists in a. In your code, you were doing `item['name'].lower()` which returns `ORANGES_060222` which doesn't exists in b. What you probably wanted to check if orange part from `a[0]` existed in b.

---

You can also do it as -

```
f = []
a = [{'name': 'ORANGES_060222', 'bushels': 5}, {'name': 'BANANAS_062620', 'bushels': 3}]
b = ['oranges', 'bananas', 'apples']
for item in a:
    if item['name'].lower().split('_')[0] in b:
        f.append(item['bushels'])
        
print(f)
```

**Output :**

```
[5, 3]
```

This method can be used if every element in a occurs in the format - `NAME_NUMBER`. So, `item['name'].lower().split('_')[0]` will only return the name part ( `oranges` in the first case ) and then you can check if it exists in b to get the desired results.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

You should do the reverse:

```
f = []
a = [{'name': 'ORANGES_060222', 'bushels': 5}, {'name': 'BANANAS_062620', 'bushels': 3}]
b = ['oranges', 'bananas', 'apples']
for item in a:
    for x in b:
        if b in item['name'].lower():
            f.append(item['bushels'])
            break
    print(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this nested list comprehension:

```
f = [item['bushels'] for item in a for d in b if d in item['name'].lower()]
```